# child component pass props to parent's useState -> returning undefined (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I want to put the props from the child component into the value of useState from the parent component, but it also comes with undefined. How can I not get undefined?

Child component

```
const FilterSelect = props => {
  const [filterUser, setFilterUser] = useState('all')

  const handleFilterUser = ({ target }) => {
    setFilterUser(target.value)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    props.propFunction(filterUser)
  }, [filterUser])

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <Select
          size="small"
          labelId="user-select-label"
          id="user-select"
          value={filterUser}
          label="filter"
          onChange={handleFilterUser}
        >
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

parent component

```
import FilterSelect from './components/FilterSelect'

const UserList = () => {
  const [filterSelectOne, setFilterSelectOne] = useState('all')

  const highFunction = text => {
    setFilterSelectOne(text)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    highFunction()
  }, [])

  console.log(filterSelectOne) // 'all', undefined

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Paper sx={{ width: '100%', mb: 2 }}>
        <FilterSelect propFunction={highFunction} />
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: `highFunction` is supposed to have parameter, in `useEffect` no parameter is passed in parent component

Answer (score 1):

Remove the use effect where you call the `highFunction` with no parameters in the parent component

Comment: It was a simple thing! Thank you so much

Comment: @many-yun no problem, you usually accept an answer if it solved the issue, or for this very simple case you could also delete your question